# autocomplete tag synonyms

Tags: bug, asking-questions, tag-synonyms, retagging, tags

When retagging (or asking) a question on [the main site](http://judaism.stackexchange.com), you can type in tag names, and they will autocomplete for you. That used to work with synonyms also (for example, I'd type in `diaspor`, and `chutz-laaretz` would come up). Now, it works only if I type in the *entire* synonym (e.g. `diaspora`).

Can this be reverted to the way it was before?

Comment: related http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1776/759

Comment: @DoubleAA, likely related. Note though that that's about the tag search page and this is about questions.

Comment: Note: If the answer is "no", then we should implement something like http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/68 in order to allow people to type in synonyms more easily.

Comment: This seems to be a bug: I see this for some synonyms, but not others. For example typing `adath` does complete [tag:yekke]=[tag:adath-jeshurun]. I see something similar on other sites, e.g. on [cs.se] typing `rewriting-s` doesn't show `rewriting-systems` (synonym of `term-rewriting`) but typing `ds.a` does show `ds.algorithms` (synonym of `algorithms`). This doesn't seem to be related to merging (all the CS synonyms I tried are merged) or to having a nonzero number of renames.

Comment: I have reported some similar problems (which I discovered on another site) on meta.SO: [Existing tag not shown when searching in the list of tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224818/existing-tag-not-shown-when-searching-in-the-list-of-tags). The tags which caused problems also contained dash.